# Parse html entities in Powershell

Tags: html, xml, powershell, tfs

I am using Microsoft Team Foundation Server via Powershell.
The task I want to do is to get and set "Steps" for a given work item of type "Test Case".

For some reason unknown to me, TFS stores such information as *HTML within XML*, where the HTML elements are written using *HTML entities*, in order not to mess up with the XML.

Here's an example:

```
<steps id="0" last="3">
    <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;I do this and that&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <description/>
    </step>
    <step id="3" type="ActionStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;I do something else &lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;This happens &lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <description/>
    </step>
</steps>
```

Which appears as:
[image: Screenshot of how TFS renders the steps for the test case]

How can I get the "bare text" of each item? For instance, `This happens` out of `&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;This happens &lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;`.
Do I have to write my own parser or is there already something that I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's something in the `System.Web` namespace that can help you:

```
PS> add-type -AssemblyName system.web
PS> [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode("Baskin &amp; Robbins")
Baskin & Robbins
```

**Update**

I read your question again and you want more than that. It's a little tricky if you are not familiar with both xml and html semantics, so here's a script for you that I knocked together. I hope you can modify it for your needs.

```powershell
add-type -AssemblyName system.web

$raw = @'
<steps id="0" last="3">
    <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;I do this and that&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <description/>
    </step>
    <step id="3" type="ActionStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;I do something else &lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">
            &lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;This happens &lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;
        </parameterizedString>
        <description/>
    </step>
</steps>
'@

$xml = [xml]$raw

$xml.steps.step | foreach-object { 
  write-host ('Processing {0}...' -f $_.type)

  $_.parameterizedString | foreach-object {
    # decode html entities
    $html = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($_.innerText)

    # let's hope the html is balanced and valid xhtml (matching begin/end tags)
    # assumption is that the innermost <P> wraps the desired text
    # match with xpath
    $text = ([xml]$html).SelectSingleNode('//P/text()').value

    write-host "Text: '$text'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Since I am also interested in "setting" those fields (to programmatically write test cases), it is a nice surprise to discover that there is a complementary method called `HtmlEncode`.

Comment: When you use the XML parser like this, there is no need to decode entities. `$_.innerText` already retrieves the decoded string, so `HtmlDecode()` is superfluous.